# Как подключиться к PDO через константы?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8", "root", "");
```

Как вписать константы для подключения?

Comment: Определить константы и вписать. Что не получается?

Answer (score 2):

```
define("DB_HOST", "DB_NAME");
define("DB_NAME", "DB_NAME");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```